# Key binding to a sequence of commands

Tags: key-bindings, functions, quote

I'm trying to define a key binding that executes a sequence of commands. I add this code to my `~/.emacs` file

```
(require 'origami)
(defun open-close-node ()
  "Open/Close node origami mode"
  (interactive)
  ('origami-open-node)
  ('origami-close-node))

(define-key origami-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-f") 'open-close-node)
```

Emacs start with no errors, but when i try to use the key binding, shows this `open-close-node: Invalid function: (quote origami-open-node)`

**EDIT:**

What i really trying is to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29946204/7760131) to my case.
By the way, I'm pretty new with lisp language.

*I just want a fast key binding to open/close the nodes within `origami-mode`*

Comment: Not sure what you're attempting to do with your function, but the errors you're getting are because you have a quoted symbol (`'origami-open-node`) within the parentheses where elisp is expecting an unquoted symbol.  I'd suggest you have a look at an [elisp tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/) to get a better feel for how lisp syntax works.

Comment: @Dan: Please consider posting that as an answer, so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: @GabrielSandoval: Please explain why you wrote the code the way you did.    I.e. where did you find the `('origami-open-node)` syntax?

Comment: @Stefan I'm really dumb with lisp language, i was trying to avoid the initial errors when emacs start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you're attempting to do with your command.  However, the error message you're getting is due to the fact that you have a *quoted* symbol (`'origami-open-node`) where elisp is expecting an unquoted symbol.

Here's a rough way to think about how lisp understands what you want it to do:

```
(verb noun noun noun noun...)
```

The first element of the lisp expression is a function (unless you use a quote, which is itself a verb), which does something (often using the other elements of the list).  When you quote a function, you turn it into the noun form of the verb.  Hence, you told lisp to use the nouned form of `origami-open-node` rather than to use `origami-open-node` *as* a verb.

Have a look at an [elisp tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/) to get a better feel for lisp syntax.

Comment: You could mention that `('origami-open-node) ` expands to `((quote origami-open-node))`,